# Tensorflow, uninitialized variables despite running global_variable_initializer

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm new to Tensorflow. I worked in Caffe previously. I'm trying to implement http://cvlab.cse.msu.edu/pdfs/Tai_Yang_Liu_CVPR2017.pdf in Tensorflow.

I'm having trouble with variables in Tensorflow, despite having them initialized. I tried using tf.get_variable instead of tf.Variable, but this didn't work. And setting initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer() did nothing.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys, os
import numpy as np

global xseed

def get_model(inp, train):
    #create architecture
    #db input, 128 batch size
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        inl = tf.reshape(inp, [-1, 31, 31, 1])

    with tf.name_scope('batchnorm_scale_relu'):
        #batchnorm,scale,relu
        normed = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inl, is_training=train)

        alpha = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((1,), stddev=0.1), trainable=True, name="alpha")
        beta = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((1,), stddev=0.1), trainable=True, name="beta")
        scaled = alpha * normed + beta

        relud = tf.nn.relu(scaled, name="relu1")

    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
        #??? padding ??? is correct
        padded_input = tf.pad(relud, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], "CONSTANT")
        #weight initializer msra
        convolved = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=padded_input, filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding="VALID",
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(seed=xseed))

    with tf.name_scope('batchnorm_scale_relu_1a'):
        #batchnorm,scale,relu
        normed_1a = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(convolved, is_training=train)

        alpha_1a = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((1,), stddev=0.1), trainable=True, name="alpha_1a")
        beta_1a = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((1,), stddev=0.1), trainable=True, name="beta_1a")
        scaled_1a = alpha_1a * normed_1a + beta_1a

        relud_1a = tf.nn.relu(scaled_1a, name="relu1_1a")

    with tf.name_scope('conv1_1a'):
        padded_input_1a = tf.pad(relud_1a, [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], "CONSTANT")
        #weight initializer msra
        convolved_1a = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=padded_input_1a, filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding="VALID",
                kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(seed=xseed))
    return convolved_1a

xseed = None
with tf.device("cpu"):
    inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 31, 31, 1])
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_op2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto()) as sess:
        m = get_model(inp, True)
        sess.run(init_op)
        sess.run(init_op2)
        print(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))
        res = sess.run(m, feed_dict={ inp: np.zeros((1, 31, 31, 1))})
```

And it reports uninitialized variables:

```
['BatchNorm/beta' 'BatchNorm/moving_mean' 'BatchNorm/moving_variance'  'batchnorm_scale_relu/alpha' 'batchnorm_scale_relu/beta' 'conv2d/kernel'  'conv2d/bias' 'BatchNorm_1/beta' 'BatchNorm_1/moving_mean'  'BatchNorm_1/moving_variance' 'batchnorm_scale_relu_1a/alpha_1a'  'batchnorm_scale_relu_1a/beta_1a' 'conv2d_1/kernel' 'conv2d_1/bias']
```

And gives me an exception when evaluating convolved tensor:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value batchnorm_scale_relu_1a/alpha_1a
     [[Node: batchnorm_scale_relu_1a/alpha_1a/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@batchnorm_scale_relu_1a/alpha_1a"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](batchnorm_scale_relu_1a/alpha_1a)]]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it myself. Replaced this:

```
with tf.device("cpu"):
    inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 31, 31, 1])
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_op2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto()) as sess:
        m = get_model(inp, True)
        sess.run(init_op)
        sess.run(init_op2)
        print(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))
        res = sess.run(m, feed_dict={ inp: np.zeros((1, 31, 31, 1))})
```

With this:

```
with tf.device("cpu"):
    inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 31, 31, 1])

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto()) as sess:
        m = get_model(inp, True)
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        res = sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables())
        #print(res) -- outputs [] (none)
        res = sess.run(m, feed_dict={ inp: np.zeros((1, 31, 31, 1))})
        print(res)
```

The whole point is tf.initialize_all_variables() instead of tf.global_variables_initializer()

Comment: The whole point is not initializer but **ordering**. In the correct one you call initializer constructor **after** building your model, thus it builds ops to initialize each component of the network. In the incorrect one (first) you ask it to provide initialisation prior to model construction thus these ops do not initialise your model (as they are not yet aware of it)